# Hall Effect on a spiral

Tags: electromagnetism, hall-effect

A flat spiral in immersed in a homogeneous magnetic field. An electric current is flowing in the spiral. The directions of the B field, the spiral and the current can be seen in the picture. As the result of the electric current and the B field, Lorentz Force appears acting on the electrons, aka the Hall Effect. The electrons are flowing from the edge to the center of the spiral, the Lorentz Force F also points to the center. Seemingly the Lorentz Force is helping the electrons to move to the center of the spiral. If that reasoning is correct, can we say that e.m.f. (electromotive force) is created because of the Lorentz Force? The bigger is the current, the bigger the emf gets, as opposed to the Ohm Law. Voltage is created out of nothing. How would you justify the energy conservation? If you think I am wrong, please point out my mistake concretely.

[image]

Comment: The force/agency that's maintaining the current seems like it's responsible for the EMF here, not the magnetic field.

Answer (score 1):

> Seemingly the Lorentz Force is helping the electrons to move the center of the spiral.

No, because the Lorentz Force is always perpendicular to the current, so it's not accelerating the electrons along the spiral.

Charged particles cannot gain energy in a homogeneous magnetic field.

Comment: Imagine that there is water instead of electrons. Instead of a spiral wire there is a spiral hose. And instead of the Lorentz Force, the centrifugal force is acting radially in the fluid because we are spinning the spiral. My reasoning tells me that if the outer end of the hose is open the water will move along out of the hose. So this is the work done by a radial force.

Comment: Yes, but the Lorentz Force is not pointing exactly toward the center. That's were the analogy breaks down. It would point radially inward if the electrons were moving in a circle, but since they move in a spiral, it doesn't. If you don't believe me, draw a spiral with less winding and draw the Lorentz force vectors on different points along the spiral.

Comment: You can accelerate water in a spiral hose by spinning it precisely because the direction of the centrifugal force is not exactly perpendicular to the direction in which the water is moving. There is a small component of the force along the direction of the spiral. For the Lorentz Force, that's not the case.

Comment: That's ok, I believe you.